php artisan l5-swagger:generate
enter image description here
l5-swagger in config file 
'annotations' => [  base_path('app/Swagger'), // You should add this line to work
base_path('app/'), ],
add but don't work why
Most commonly this manifests with a warning about the required @OA\Info not being found. While most annotations have specific related code, the info annotation (and a few more) is kind of global.
The simplest solution to avoid this issue is to add a 'dummy' class to the docblock and add all 'global' annotations (e.g. Tag, Server, SecurityScheme, etc.) in a single docblock to that class.
